# Oozie not starting in Amazon EMR

Tags: oozie

I tried to install Apache oozie in EMR cluster. I am getting the error. “Error: IO_ERROR : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused”.

Followed the below link for installation: 
http://pkavuri.blogspot.in/2013/08/oozie-installation-is-simplified.html

I got the error after running the below command:

> `bin/oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status`

The following steps I did after encountering the error:

- Moved the Hadoop and common jar files to the folders
  “/oozie-3.3.2/distro/target/oozie-3.3.2-distro/oozie-3.3.2/oozie-server/webapps/oozie/WEB-INF/lib”
  and “oozie-3.3.2/distro/target/oozie-3.3.2-distro/oozie-3.3.2/lib/”
- Downloaded derby in oozie-3.3.2/libext

The error trace after running the command "tail -100f logs/catalina.out":

> ERROR: Oozie could not be started
>
> REASON: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils
>
> Stacktrace:
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/util/ReflectionUtils
>           at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.setServiceInternal(Services.java:359)
>           at org.apache.oozie.service.Services.(Services.java:108)
>           at org.apache.oozie.servlet.ServicesLoader.contextInitialized(ServicesLoader.java:38)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Caused
>   by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>
> ### ... 27 more

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a libext folder and put all hadoop jars , extjs jars in it . Then run oozie-setup.sh and then oozie-run.sh

In this case based on your logs i guess you are missing hadoop-core.jar.